# TIFF viewer plugin for Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, tiff, google-chrome-extensions

Is there a TIFF viewer extension for Chrome, I found [AlternaTIFF](http://www.alternatiff.com/), but cannot make it work in chrome. I am trying to view images on the [USPTO.gov website](http://www.uspto.gov/patft/help/images.htm).

Tried [suggestions here](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=3e5c1758d5497670&hl=en) also, no luck

Comment: AlternaTIFF is inaccessible for me, so I can't try it out - but, does it work in IE? If so, you can use IE Tab to make USPTO links open in IETab

Comment: IE is a swear word to me, might have to though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out a workaround, Install AlternaTIFF for IE, then [install IE Tab](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hehijbfgiekmjfkfjpbkbammjbdenadd) for Chrome, navigate to the TIFF page in chrome then click the IE tab button, wahlah, you can now view USPTO TIFF pages in Chrome!

[Got the idea from this page](http://www.blackice.com/tiffviewer-chrome.htm), but Black Ice costs $$, so I figured maybe it will work with AlternaTIFF for IE, and it did.

.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

ITV - Inline Tiff Viewer is free and easy to use.  It replaces tiff objects or img tags on any page with a converted png.  It can then be dragged around the screen and zoomed in and out with the mouse wheel.

[ITV in Google Play](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/inline-tiff-viewer/kkfncbfgbghoklckdmeljdjohpkknlma)

Comment: Welcome to Superuser.  Please take the tour at https://superuser.com/Tour to get the most out of this site.